# Segfault when QueryObject leaves function scope

Tags: drake

The following code segfaults:

```
from pydrake.all import (
    Diagram,
    DiagramBuilder,
    AddMultibodyPlantSceneGraph,
    UnitInertia,
    SpatialInertia,
    MultibodyPlant,
    SceneGraph,
    QueryObject,
)
import numpy as np


def get_query_object(
    diagram: Diagram,
    plant: MultibodyPlant,
    scene_graph: SceneGraph,
    q: np.ndarray,
) -> QueryObject:
    context = diagram.CreateDefaultContext()
    plant_context = diagram.GetMutableSubsystemContext(plant, context)
    plant.SetPositions(plant_context, q)
    sg_context = diagram.GetMutableSubsystemContext(scene_graph, context)
    query_object = (
        scene_graph.get_query_output_port().EvalAbstract(sg_context).get_value()
    )
    return query_object


builder = DiagramBuilder()

plant, scene_graph = AddMultibodyPlantSceneGraph(builder, 1e-4)
plant.AddRigidBody(
    "body",
    SpatialInertia(1, [0, 0, 0], UnitInertia(1, 1, 1)),
)

plant.Finalize()
diagram = builder.Build()

q = np.zeros(7)

query_object = get_query_object(
    diagram=diagram,
    plant=plant,
    scene_graph=scene_graph,
    q=q,
)
signed_distance_pair = query_object.ComputeSignedDistancePairwiseClosestPoints()
```

The segfault can be avoided by inlining the contents of *get_query_object* or by executing *ComputeSignedDistancePairwiseClosestPoints* inside of it, so I take it that the problem lies in doing geometric queries using a QueryObject that has left the scope in which it was created. The Drake documentation has a warning about *QueryObject* which I believe relates to this:

> "The const reference returned by the input port is considered 'live' -
> it is linked to the context, system, and cache (making full use of all
> of those mechanisms). This const reference should never be persisted;
> doing so can lead to erroneous query results. It is simpler and more
> advisable to acquire it for evaluation in a limited scope (e.g.,
> CalcTimeDerivatives()) and then discard it. If a QueryObject is needed
> for many separate functions in a LeafSystem, each should re-evaluate
> the input port. The underlying caching mechanism should make the cost
> of this negligible."

Here's my usecase: I wrote a bunch of functions that use geometry queries, like non-penetration constraints and contact jacobians. All of these use a lot of boilerplate for setting up a *QueryObject*, so I thought I'd wrap that boilerplate up in a *get_query_object* function, which the other functions would call and then run whichever geometric query they needed in it. This *sounds* safe to me, as each function is setting up its own *QueryObject* and it doesn't exit the scope of that function, so we shouldn't run into the problem described in the documentation. But it clearly doesn't work---so what is the recommended workflow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you have is that `get_query_object` *creates* a context that gets thrown out upon return. At the highest level, you should think of `QueryObject` as a *view* into the `Context` that can perform specific queries; it stores no data. No `Context` and your `QueryObject` dies.

Your function attempts to do two things:

1. Set some positions for a multibody plant.
2. Get a query object so you can compute signed distance.

Although you're tripping over the fact that the query object is now dead, your other problem is that the body positions you set got destroyed with the context as well.

I'd recommend the following changes:

1. Create the context and store it at a similar scope as the diagram, plant, and scene graph.
2. Get the query object associated with *that* context and just hang onto it. It will be valid and "live" as long as the context (i.e., it will *always* be a view into that context's data). Alternatively, as the documentation suggests, `QueryObject` instances are cheap. You can just go get one from the context whenever you need one.
3. Create a method whose sole purpose is to set the body positions for a plant in that same context.

This should give you the functionality you're looking for.

The warning in the documentation you pasted refers to the fact that the query object is live. If you hang on to that reference and *the data in the context changes* you'll get different answers. The answers will always reflect the current state of the associated context.

Comment: Thank you, this is very clear and helpful! Small follow-up question: when operating with e.g. a set of functions implementing constraints on an optimization problem, is the best practice then to have each function create a context within its scope? I imagine that must cause some overhead, but the alternative---where we have a shared context and each function merely sets positions within that context---seems problematic, as the functions are now impure and one can imagine problems stemming from modification of that same context. What's the sanest implementation?

Comment: Presumably, the set of constraints are all *alternatives*, right? Not a set of constraints to be satisfied simultaneously. More generally, if you're planning on doing a bunch of "parallel" analysis (whether you literally do that in a multi-threaded context or not), having a per-analysis dedicated context guarantees you that each problem will remain untouched by anything the others do. The memory overhead is pretty small. You'd have to have a *massive* number of threads (highly unlikely).