# Debugging segfault when calling ComputeSignedDistancePairwiseClosestPoints in PyDrake

Tags: drake

I'm running an optimization loop that repeatedly calls `ComputeSignedDistancePairwiseClosestPoints`. After hundreds of cumulative hours of running this without problems, I've encountered a segfault and am looking for guidance on debugging it (or if it's a bug in Drake, possible temporary workarounds).

As suggested in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67035352/segfault-when-queryobject-leaves-function-scope), upon initialization, I store diagram, plant, and scene graph contexts, and before calling `ComputeSignedDistancePairwiseClosestPoints`, I call the query object output port evaluated at the stored scene graph context. Here is a rough outline of the relevant code structure:

```
class SimplifiedClass:

    def __init__(self, ...):
        # initializing plant, contexts, and query object port
        self.diagram = function_generating_diagram_with_plant(...)
        self.plant = self.diagram.GetSubsystemByName("plant")
        self.scene_graph = self.diagram.GetSubsystemByName("scene_graph")

        _diag_context = self.diagram.CreateDefaultContext()
        self.plant_context = self.plant.GetMyMutableContextFromRoot(_diag_context)
        self.sg_context = self.scene_graph.GetMyMutableContextFromRoot(_diag_context)

        self.qo_port = self.scene_graph.get_query_output_port()

    @property
    def query_object(self):
        return self.qo_port.Eval(self.sg_context)

    def function_that_computes_signed_distances(self, ...):
        # this function calls ComputeSignedDistancePairClosestPoints()
        # it is called repeatedly in an optimization loop
        
        # line that computes signed distance pairs after other operations
        sdps = self.query_object.ComputeSignedDistancePairwiseClosestPoints(
            max_distance=some_number
        )
```

I can reproduce the segfault by fixing the random seed appropriately, and I find that when changing the `max_distance` parameter of `ComputeSignedDistancePairwiseClosestPoints`, the segfault no longer occurs for this specific seed.

I printed a `gdb` backtrace which returns the following:

```
#0  0x00007f21a9149be5 in ?? () from /opt/drake/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pydrake/common/../../../../libdrake.so
#1  0x00007f21a914cc46 in ?? () from /opt/drake/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pydrake/common/../../../../libdrake.so
#2  0x00007f21a914cca5 in ?? () from /opt/drake/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pydrake/common/../../../../libdrake.so
#3  0x00007f21a914cca5 in ?? () from /opt/drake/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pydrake/common/../../../../libdrake.so
#4  0x00007f21a914cca5 in ?? () from /opt/drake/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pydrake/common/../../../../libdrake.so
#5  0x00007f21a914cca5 in ?? () from /opt/drake/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pydrake/common/../../../../libdrake.so
#6  0x00007f21a914cca5 in ?? () from /opt/drake/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pydrake/common/../../../../libdrake.so
#7  0x00007f21a914cca5 in ?? () from /opt/drake/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pydrake/common/../../../../libdrake.so
#8  0x00007f21a914cca5 in ?? () from /opt/drake/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pydrake/common/../../../../libdrake.so
#9  0x00007f21a914d61b in ?? () from /opt/drake/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pydrake/common/../../../../libdrake.so
#10 0x00007f21a914ba3a in ?? () from /opt/drake/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pydrake/common/../../../../libdrake.so
#11 0x00007f21a914bbdc in ?? () from /opt/drake/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pydrake/common/../../../../libdrake.so
#12 0x00007f21a919f324 in ?? () from /opt/drake/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pydrake/common/../../../../libdrake.so
#13 0x00007f21a9165123 in ?? () from /opt/drake/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pydrake/common/../../../../libdrake.so
#14 0x00007f21a918961a in ?? () from /opt/drake/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pydrake/common/../../../../libdrake.so
#15 0x00007f21a918d29d in ?? () from /opt/drake/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pydrake/common/../../../../libdrake.so
#16 0x00007f21a918fdd2 in ?? () from /opt/drake/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pydrake/common/../../../../libdrake.so
#17 0x00007f21a92a9496 in void drake::geometry::internal::shape_distance::CalcDistanceFallback<double>(fcl::CollisionObject<double> const&, fcl::CollisionObject<double> const&, fcl::DistanceRequest<double> const&, drake::geometry::SignedDistancePair<double>*) () from /opt/drake/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pydrake/common/../../../../libdrake.so
#18 0x00007f21a92a9aa5 in bool drake::geometry::internal::shape_distance::Callback<double>(fcl::CollisionObject<double>*, fcl::CollisionObject<double>*, void*, double&) ()
   from /opt/drake/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pydrake/common/../../../../libdrake.so
#19 0x00007f21a91e98ca in ?? () from /opt/drake/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pydrake/common/../../../../libdrake.so
#20 0x00007f21a91e99b2 in ?? () from /opt/drake/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pydrake/common/../../../../libdrake.so
#21 0x00007f21a91e998b in ?? () from /opt/drake/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pydrake/common/../../../../libdrake.so
#22 0x00007f21a91e998b in ?? () from /opt/drake/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pydrake/common/../../../../libdrake.so
#23 0x00007f21a91e998b in ?? () from /opt/drake/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pydrake/common/../../../../libdrake.so
#24 0x00007f21a91e99b2 in ?? () from /opt/drake/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pydrake/common/../../../../libdrake.so
#25 0x00007f21a91e99b2 in ?? () from /opt/drake/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pydrake/common/../../../../libdrake.so
#26 0x00007f21a91e998b in ?? () from /opt/drake/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pydrake/common/../../../../libdrake.so
#27 0x00007f21a91e9a26 in ?? () from /opt/drake/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pydrake/common/../../../../libdrake.so
#28 0x00007f21a933a01e in drake::geometry::internal::ProximityEngine<double>::ComputeSignedDistancePairwiseClosestPoints(std::unordered_map<drake::geometry::GeometryId, drake::math::RigidTransform<double>, std::hash<drake::geometry::GeometryId>, std::equal_to<drake::geometry::GeometryId>, std::allocator<std::pair<drake::geometry::GeometryId const, drake::math::RigidTransform<double> > > > const&, double) const ()
   from /opt/drake/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pydrake/common/../../../../libdrake.so
#29 0x00007f21a93ab1fc in drake::geometry::QueryObject<double>::ComputeSignedDistancePairwiseClosestPoints(double) const () from /opt/drake/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pydrake/common/../../../../libdrake.so
#30 0x00007f20bf6f2327 in ?? () from /opt/drake/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pydrake/geometry.cpython-310-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
#31 0x00007f20bf547c4f in ?? () from /opt/drake/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pydrake/geometry.cpython-310-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
#32 0x00005604e39c1b5e in ?? ()
#33 0x00005604e39b87db in _PyObject_MakeTpCall ()
#34 0x00005604e39d066b in ?? ()
#35 0x00005604e39ac2fc in _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault ()
#36 0x00005604e39c23ac in _PyFunction_Vectorcall ()
#37 0x00005604e39ab14a in _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault ()
#38 0x00005604e39d0391 in ?? ()
#39 0x00005604e39ac2fc in _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault ()
#40 0x00005604e39c23ac in _PyFunction_Vectorcall ()
#41 0x00005604e39ab14a in _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault ()
#42 0x00005604e39c23ac in _PyFunction_Vectorcall ()
... (more in this trace omitted since it's not Drake-specific)
```

Comment: Do you know what geometry is causing the error? Drake calls FCL to compute the signed distance for many geometry types, on the other hand, for simple geometries, like sphere-to-sphere distance Drake computes it internally. I suspect this is a problem of FCL instead of Drake.

Comment: There are dozens of possible candidates, and I can't determine which geometry is causing the error. I have both primitives like boxes, capsules, spheres, etc. as well as `Convex` shapes generated by V-HACD for collision geometry. Perhaps it's related to the issue here I faced a few weeks ago: https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/issues/18704.

Comment: Do you have any recourse to running this with a debug build? As it is, the stack trace isn't particularly helpful.

Comment: I didn't know about the profiling tools before you mentioned debug builds - thanks for pointing me that way. I'm currently running Drake using one of the provided Docker images - is there a low-friction way for me to incorporate the profiling tools into my existing workflow (e.g. with, say a multi-stage Docker build) or would I need to build from source?

Comment: You can build [from source](https://drake.mit.edu/from_source.html) via CMake and install that yourself in Docker, but I don't think debugging via stackoverflow comments will work well.

If you can create a self-contained reproduction recipe (even if it's somewhat large), please post that code+data attachment as a Drake bug report.  Then the Drake team can investigate and root cause why Drake is failing.